# How do I return value from AsyncTask class to another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an option menu item that allows a user to see their current location (based on Zip Code) on **Google Maps** using an **intent**. Because Google Maps only accepts Lat/Lng, I am using the **Geocoding API** to return Lat/Lng in **JSON** format. Here is the code that executes once the user selects the menu item:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
  Intent in = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
  startActivity(in);
  return true;
}
if (id == R.id.action_map) {
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_location_key),
      getString(R.string.pref_location_default));
  FetchZipTask fzt = new FetchZipTask();
  fzt.execute(location);
  loc = fzt.locale;
  Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:"+ loc);
  Log.d("Debug", geoLocation.toString());
  Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  in.setData(geoLocation);
  if (in.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(in);
  }
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I am currently trying to use a public String field in the **AsyncTask** class that is updated when the `onPostExecute()` method parses the **JSON** and formats the retrieved Lat/Lng string. I then access this public field from the **MainActivity** class whenever the user selects the menu item, but the field is always null. What am I doing wrong, and is it the most effective way to leverage **AsyncTask**? I'm thinking there must be a better way to return the value.

**FetchZipTask.java**

```
public class FetchZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public String locale = null;

@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
locale = result;
}

@Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

if (params.length == 0) {
  return null;
}

HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;

//raw JSON response as a string
String locationJsonStr = null;

try {
  final String BASE_LOCATION_URL =       


"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
  final String ADDRESS_PARAM = "address";
  final String APPID_PARAM = "key";

  // URI.path vs URI.parse vs. URI Scheme
  Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_LOCATION_URL)
      .buildUpon()
      .appendQueryParameter(ADDRESS_PARAM, params[0])
      .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, BuildConfig.GOOGLE_GEOCODE_API_KEY)
      .build();
  //Log.d("Debug", builtUri.toString());

  URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

  urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  urlConnection.connect();

  // Read the input stream into a String
  InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  if (inputStream == null) {
    // Nothing to do.
    return null;
  }
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

  String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    // buffer for debugging.
    line.concat(" Hello ");
    line.concat("\n");
    buffer.append(line);
  }

  if (buffer.length() == 0) {
    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
    return null;
  }
  locationJsonStr = buffer.toString();

  Log.v("debug", "Location string: " + locationJsonStr);
 } catch (IOException e) {

  return null;
 } finally {
  if (urlConnection != null) {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
  }
  if (reader != null) {
    try {
      reader.close();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
      Log.e("ForecastFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
    }
  }
}
try {
  return getLocationDataFromJson(locationJsonStr);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}

private String getLocationDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr) throws          
JSONException {
// These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
final String GEO_LIST = "results";
final String GEO_OBJ = "geometry";
final String GEO_LOC = "location";
final String GEO_LAT = "lat";
final String GEO_LNG = "lng";

JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
JSONArray resultsArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(GEO_LIST);
JSONObject resultsObj = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject geoObj = resultsObj.getJSONObject(GEO_OBJ);
JSONObject latLng = geoObj.getJSONObject(GEO_LOC);
String lat = latLng.getString(GEO_LAT);
String lng = latLng.getString(GEO_LNG);

Log.d("location", "Lat:" + lat + "\n Lng:" + lng);

return lat + "," + lng;
}
}
```

Comment: first of all did you check **onPostExecute(String result)** returning values or not?if you are not getting values then **doInBackground(String... params)** **return** should be ** return getLocationDataFromJson(locationJsonStr);** and should not be **return null**

Comment: doInBackground() is returning getLocationDataFromJson(), in the try/catch block. onPostExecute is returning the correct string. But that string is not making it back to my MainActivity.

Comment: @RustDev You're trying to access that `String` before it is even fetched. See my answer below.

Comment: @RustDev bro...remove this line in activity.**loc = fzt.locale;** and try to call http://pastebin.com/iGw5AM20 this in **onPostExecute(String result)** method..

Comment: I am going to try user13's approach, because the FetchZipTask class would be used as a utility class for other situations as well, not just for the menu item selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is called async for a reason.

In the following code you execute your `AsyncTask` and then immediately try to access one of its fields:

```
FetchZipTask fzt = new FetchZipTask();
fzt.execute(location);
loc = fzt.locale;
```

That won't work because `FetchZipTask` may still be running when you're trying to access its `locale` variable.

`onPostExecute()` is called when the task is finished, so you should pass your result from there.

You could define an interface in `FetchZipTask`, pass an instance of it as a constructor param and call the appropriate method on that instance in `onPostExecute()`:

```
public class FetchZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // declaring a listener instance
    private OnFetchFinishedListener listener;

    // the listener interface
    public interface OnFetchFinishedListener {
        void onFetchFinished(String result);
    }

    // getting a listener instance from the constructor
    public FetchZipTask(OnFetchFinishedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // ...

    // calling a method of the listener with the result
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onFetchFinished(result);
    }
}
```

In your `Activity`, pass an `OnFetchFinishedListener` when instantiating your `AsyncTask`:

```
new FetchZipTask(new FetchZipTask.OnFetchFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFetchFinished(String result) {
            // do whatever you want with the result

            Uri geoLocation = Uri.parse("geo:"+ result);
            Log.d("Debug", geoLocation.toString());
            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            in.setData(geoLocation);
            if (in.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    }).execute();
```

And that's it. Orientation change may still be a problem, so you could move your `AsyncTask` in a headless `Fragment`, or consider using a `Service` instead.